# Node.js testing RESTful API (vows.js?)

Tags: testing, node.js, vows

I could really do with some advice on testing a RESTful api I created in node.js. There are a plethora of frameworks out there and I am at a loss. My testing knowledge isn't good enough generally which is why I am trying to write these tests. I've tried vows.js which seems nice but I couldn't work out how to incorporate the testing of my API, I need some sort of client. An example of a simple post to test a login system is all I need to get going.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update 6 months later

vows-is sucks. use [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha)

### Original

**Updated with [vow-is](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is) code**

Here's the vows-is example from the [vows-is examples folder](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is/blob/master/examples/simple-http.js).

```
// simple HTTP
// Run with node example/simple-http.js

var express = require("express");
    is = require("../src/vows-is.js");

is.config({
    "server": {
        "factory": function _factory(cb) {
            var app = express.createServer();

            app.get("/", function(req, res) {
                res.send("hello world");
            })

            app.listen(3000);

            cb(app);
        },
        "uri": "http://localhost:3000",
        "kill": function _kill(app) {
            app.close();
        }
    }
});

is.suite("http request test").batch()

    .context("a request to GET /")
        .topic.is.a.request("GET /")
        .vow.it.should.have.status(200)
        .vow.it.should.have
            .header("content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        .context("contains a body that")
            .topic.is.property('body')
            .vow.it.should.be.ok
            .vow.it.should.include.string("hello world")

.suite().run({
    reporter: is.reporter
}, function() {
    console.log("finished");
    is.end();
})
```

This uses [vows-is](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is).

Answer (score 4):

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/rest-easy-test-any-api-in-nodejs is designed for this very purpose.  It's a DSL that sits on top of Vows that streamlines the process of writing out tests using vows.

Basic test:

```
//
// Here we will configure our tests to use 
// http://localhost:8080 as the remote address
// and to always send 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
//
suite.use('localhost', 8000)
     .setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     //
     // A GET Request to /ping
     //   should respond with 200
     //   should respond with { pong: true }
     //
     .get('/ping')
       .expect(200, { pong: true })
     //
     // A POST Request to /ping
     //   should respond with 200
     //   should respond with { dynamic_data: true }
     //
     .post('/ping', { dynamic_data: true })
       .expect(200, { dynamic_data: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used [vowsjs](http://vowsjs.org/) and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) libraries.

I have found them to be the easiest as both libs are documented properly and seem to be actively developed and maintained. (I haven't found the docs for [APIeasy](https://github.com/indexzero/api-easy) to be sufficient.)

Here's an [example test](https://github.com/gryzzly/couchapp-todos/blob/API/test/api-test.js) I am writing at the moment to test Couchapp's HTTP API:

```js
var request = require ('request')
    , vows = require ('vows')
    , assert = require ('assert');

var BASE_URL = "http://local.todos.com:5984/todos/"
    , HEADERS = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    , revisionReference;

vows.describe ('CouchApp Todos REST API')
  // --------------------------------------------
  // Testing PUTs
  // ============================================
  .addBatch ({
    "A PUT to /todos/test-host without data": {
      topic : function () {
        request ({
          uri: BASE_URL + "test-host",
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: HEADERS
        }, this.callback );
      } 
      , "should respond with 201" : function ( err, res, body ) {
        assert.equal ( res.statusCode, 201 );
      }
      , "should have an id 'test-host'" : function ( err, res, body ) {
        assert.equal ( JSON.parse( res.body )._id, 'test-host' );
      }
      , "response should contain empty todos []" : function ( err, res, body ) {
        assert.include ( JSON.parse( res.body ), 'todos' );
        assert.deepEqual ( JSON.parse( res.body ).todos, [] );
      }
    }
  })
  .addBatch ({
    "A PUT to /todos/test-host with one todo item (an object)" : {
        topic : function () {
          request ({
            uri: BASE_URL + "test-host"
            , body: JSON.stringify({
                "title" : "Testing Todo",
                "isDone" : false
              })
            , method : "PUT"
            , headers : HEADERS
          }, this.callback );
        }
        , "should respond with 201" : function ( err, res, body ) {
          assert.equal ( res.statusCode, 201 );
        }
        , "should have an id 'test-host'" : function ( err, res, body ) {
          assert.equal ( JSON.parse( res.body )._id, 'test-host' )
        }
        , "response should contain todos array with one item" : function ( err, res, body ) {
          assert.include ( JSON.parse( res.body ), 'todos' );
          assert.deepEqual ( 
            JSON.parse( res.body ).todos
            , [{
              "title" : "Testing Todo",
              "isDone" : false,
              "_id" : 0
            }] 
          );
        }
    }
  })
```